# Firebase query effectiveness with queryLimited

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I am wondering about the current topic and I know that some fellow firebase experts are quite quick here to respond that's why I share it here.

If I query data from a child and limit it to the last24, does it consume the same amount as when I query only the last one and do it 2 times? (Pagination, generally I am wondering if I should query more posts at once to decrease data consumption or if its the same)

example
is it the same if I call this once

```
query.queryLimited(toLast: 2).observeSingleEvent
```

or this twice?

```
query.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent
```

just from the viewpoint of data consumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just from the viewpoint of data consumption

A quick answer is that it really depends on the size of the objects.

Let's take a quick example. Let's assume we have a node of users that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
        |
        --- $uid
        |    |
        |    --- name: "Zash__"
        |
        --- $uid
             |
             --- name: "Alex Mamo"
```

As you can see, my object is larger in size than yours, since my name contains **nine** characters while yours contains only **six**. So for the sake of this example, we could say that your object has a size of 6 bytes, while mine has 9 bytes.

So if you're using the following query:

```
query.queryLimited(toLast: 2).observeSingleEvent
```

The amount of data that will be downloaded will be (6 + 9) **15 bytes**. On the other side, if you're using the following query twice:

```
query.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent
```

The amount of data that will be downloaded will be (9 + 9) **18 bytes**, considering that the last user in the query it's me.

So the amount of data that you download will always depend on the size of the objects that you're downloading. If by chance, both objects will have **the exact same size**, then the amount of data that will be downloaded will be the same.

If you want **not** to care about the size of the objects, then you should consider using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), where it doesn't matter the size of the documents. This means that if a document is 20 bytes in size and you read it or is 1 Mib (the [maximum size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)), you'll always have to pay the same price, which is a single document read.

---

P.S. Most likely the calculation isn't done exactly that way, but it was just an example to understand the concept.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The downloaded content Is the same size, its just about if its more costly to call the .observeSingleEvent more often.

Comment: Firebase listeners are cheap. So you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Can I help you with other information?

Comment: So if my goal is to download the 4 exact same things it ends up the same costs whether I do it 4 times with getting 1 child or 1 time getting all 4 Childs at once?

Comment: Yes, if the objects have the **exact** same size, then an operation that downloads 4 items will be the same as 4 operations that download only one item. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your quick response!